# HapiJS web app inside docker container not responding

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, hapi.js

I utilize HapiJS via docker compose 2+

`.env`

```
NODE_VIEWS_PATH=../
NODE_PUBLIC_PATH=../
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mahrio
WEB_DOMAIN=http://127.0.0.1:6085
```

deep down somewhere I am setting the HapiJS stuff via these `.env` files, but for Docker I understand I need to do some changes.. no problem I made a docker specific version

`docker.env`

```
NODE_VIEWS_PATH=../
NODE_PUBLIC_PATH=../
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/mahrio
WEB_DOMAIN=http://0.0.0.0:6085
```

I've tried `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1` , neither work

I can see everything seems to work however when I goto `localhost:6085` I get no response.

`127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.`

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/mahrio
WORKDIR /usr/src/mahrio

COPY package*.json /usr/src/mahrio

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . /usr/src/mahrio

EXPOSE 6085
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: mahrio
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file:
      - docker.env
    ports:
      - "6085:6085"
    restart: always
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

any ideas ? No errors from nodejs are coming, everything looks A-OKAY at the console and I know it works outside docker just fine.

Edit: added the `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                              NAMES
25e7a4c3f350        mahriomedium_app                             "npm start"              24 hours ago        Up About a minute           0.0.0.0:6085->6085/tcp                             mahrio
c8d691777aa0        mongo                                        "docker-entrypoint..."   3 days ago          Up About a minute           0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                           mongo
```

`docker logs`

```
> mahrio-medium@0.0.1 start /usr/src/mahrio
> node server/index.js

Running Development!
MongoDB Config...
Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:6085
MongoDB connected!
db connection opened
```

Comment: if you use `docker ps -a` find the container see if its still running. `docker logs {containerId}` will tell you how the application started or if it crashed.

Comment: If you go to `http://mahrio:6085 ` can you view the application?

Comment: If it still running what does the docker logs say?

Comment: @d3l33t trying `mahrio:6085` gives the same

Comment: @ShawnC. `docker logs` added at the end, along with `docker ps output`

Comment: In your Dockerfile, try to copy files before `npm install`. I see that the node is running but who knows :)

Comment: @Andrija that had no effect

Comment: Have you tried echoing those vars from running container to see if they are ok, like `docker-compose exec mahrio sh` then `echo $WEB_DOMAIN`

Comment: You are passing the full url to hapi. Have you tried just the port like `const server = new Hapi.Server();  server.connection({port});`

Comment: @Andrija , I get `ERROR: No such service: mahrio` when trying to execute that first command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out `WEB_DOMAIN` was the wrong env var

the right var is `NODE_URI` to set to `0.0.0.0`

all works now